# using /n in CONCATENATE

Tags: excel, xlsx

I'm pretty new at more than simple spreadsheet use and could use some help.  I've been told that I can use /n instead of CHAR(10) in concatenate forumla but am finding that simply replacing it with /n is not working.

=CONCATENATE(B1," "&CHAR(10)," "&C1," "&CHAR(10)," "&CHAR(10),D1,""&CHAR(10))

Could somebody please show me what this should look like? Explaining might be helpful, but won't help without seeing the full result as I don't understand half the jargon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is tagged C++ and C.

Comment: Wrong Tags ! May be `VBA` ?

Comment: @P0W: It looks like Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is tagged badly, as that `CONCATENATE` is a built-in Excel Formula (it is in no way directly related to usage of C++).

That being said, the correct version of `CONCATENATE` is:

`=CONCATENATE(text, [text2], [text3], ...)`

And, as you want to concatenate a newline character to the cell (i.e.: `\n` **not** `/n`), you should use `CHAR(10)`. However, in order to see the newline in the cell that you've applied concatenate on, you also have to do the following:

- Right-Click the cell that you're using the `CONCATENATE` formula on.
- Select Format Options
- Under Number, select "Text" as the Category
- Under Alignment there is a sub-section called "Text-Control". Click on the checkbox that says: "Wrap text".
- Hit OK.

And, now you should see the newline reflected in whatever text you were trying to apply `CONCATENATE` on.